# Вывод инфоблока в компоненте Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь вывести инфоблоки в компоненте битрикс

**index.php**

```
    <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        "new:new.component",
        ".default",
            Array(
                "IBLOCK_ID" => "10",
                "FIELD_CODE" => array("SERVIS_NAME","SERVIS_ID", ""),
                "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("SERVIS_NAME", "SERVIS_ID", ""),
            ),
        false
    );?>
```

**template.php**

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):
    $servisName =   $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["SERVIS_NAME"]["VALUE"];
    $servisId   = $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["SERVIS_ID"]["VALUE"];
    echo $servisName;

    endforeach;
?>
```

**component.php**

```
<? if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
   $this->IncludeComponentTemplate();
?>
```

Сам компонент находится в папке:
\public_html\bitrix\components\new\new.component\
Раньше делал по аналогии в папке шаблона >...> news.list и все работало.

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Но ведь ваш компонент ничего не делает кроме подключения шаблона. Откуда возьмутся данные в `$arResult["ITEMS"]` если вы в этотм массив ничего вообще не добавляете?

Comment: А что нужно добавить. Я запутался в документации к битриксу.

Comment: Нужно добавить какой-то код, что заполнит массив `$arResult["ITEMS"]`. Я не знаю какая у вас задача.

Comment: Вывести инфоблок

Comment: Ну и зачем вы создали для этого компонент свой? `bitrix:news.list` прекрасно это делает.

Comment: Хочу попробовать через свой. Я в битриксе дилетант. Раньше через bitrix:news.list делал.

Comment: зачем пытаться делать то, что уже сделано? есть решение которое отлично справливается с поставленной задачей. кастомизировать его легко. посмотрите на состав компонента news.list если делаете его аналог